# wp PHP: a MySQL8 query using REGEXP with double backslash. Can I avoid using \\\\?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress, backslash

Due to the fact I have over 100,000 posts, I am using MySQL directly instead of wp codex for testing complex regexs for adding tags.
To also test results quickly in a visual format, I created a wordpress search page that uses the same SQL statement directly. This works with no problems unless there are escaped regex characters, such as `\b`, which in a MySQL8 statement is `\\b`.
If I use that exact statement in PHP, the double backslash is not recognised.

For example (with a simple regex):

```php
global $wpdb;
$sqlreal = "
SELECT wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE (wp_posts.post_title REGEXP '\\b(com(edy|ical)|doc(o|umentary))\\b' 
OR  wp_posts.post_content REGEXP '\\b(com(edy|ical)|doc(o|umentary))\\b' )
AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (215) ) ) 
AND (wp_posts.post_type = 'post' OR wp_posts.post_type = 'xdays1') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
";

$post_id = $wpdb->get_results($sqlreal);
$second_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post__in' => $post_id,
) );
```

etc..

this does not work because the `\\b` comes out as `\b` in PHP. I know if I write it `\\\\b` then it will work, but I am often cutting and pasting from my MySQL Workbench quickly so wondered if there is another method, such as a PHP function for having `\\b` come out as just raw text, as is, for the SQL query.

I have tried all manner of things, like:

```php
str_replace('\\\\', '\\\\\\\\', $sqlreal);


preg_quote($sqlreal);


mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $sqlreal);

\\etc
```

there seem to be quite a few similar questions in Stackoverflow but none of the methods I tried worked. It seems like there must be a simple solution? or am I stuck with having to convert all `\\b` to `\\\\b`?
Its a pain to do this when cutting and pasting SQL code for hundreds of snippets...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just found that if text is loaded from a text file, then its raw and backslashes are intact. So if I paste the SQL query into an external file and load it in PHP with `file_get_contents("data.txt")` then the text is raw without alteratation and all the backslashes are exactly the same as the original. Even when stored as a variable in PHP. Actually this is more convenient anyway.
I am all ears for any other methods nonetheless...